# Can't create user in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

When I run `CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'test'` in `sudo -u postgres psql` and run `\du` only postgres user appears... I'm not prompted anything when running commands like `ALTER USER` and I know **USER ALTERED** should appear, or something similar.

Comment: what do you see in the log? set log_statements to all and see, if the SQL actually makes it to the server. could it be some hidden password prompt or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you end the command with a semicolon?

```
CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'test';
```